# AngularJs - routing between css files

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

​Hi all.. 
referring to ngRoute,

i created a single page application but would like to apply different css rules to each sub-page like background image

how can i do that?

i assigned a different controller to each sub-page 
and in the link tag i used ng-href and {{name}}.css to tell the browser to grap the correct css file where is name is giving the value of the file name and attached to the scope inside the corresponding controller.
is there a need to use more than one  ng-controller ?
here is the view : http://shireefkhatab.github.io/imax-design
and my code : https://github.com/shireefkhatab/imax-design​

hope to get a response 
thank you all in advance.
Reefo.

Comment: put <style> tags in each template? or use $ocLazyload to load each css files on each route, or may be ui-route do that.

Comment: can i8 really use a style tag in each template when they load insidea contaner div my index.html?

Answer (score 0):

You can include those styles in your template (views) or make separate route for styles, add its view in head section and then change state from your controller using *$state.go('where.ever.you.want.to.go');*

Comment: @ Shubham: i really want your second idea but dont know how csn i do it

Comment: and regarding the first idea.. i wonder if i can add style to a div inside the body/ beacuse those snippets r loaded inside a div container which is inside the body already

Comment: are you using ngRoute or ui-router ? I will prefer you to use ui-router router for this. please visit [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router) for more information about how to use ui-router